# Can a standalone .svg be scaled to fit the browser window?

Tags: svg, browser

Here is a simple test of what I want to use SVGs for - annotation of images:

```sh
mkdir /tmp/test
cd /tmp/test

# grab an image from unsplash, 4100 px in width
wget "https://unsplash.com/photos/kSvpTrfhaiU/download?force=true&w=4100" -O unsplash_kSvpTrfhaiU.jpg

# open this image with Inkscape, have it as linked (not embedded) image, add annotations, save as unsplash_kSvpTrfhaiU.svg
inkscape unsplash_kSvpTrfhaiU.jpg
```

Right, so I'm pasting the code for the resulting .svg here:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg2"
   width="4100"
   height="3075"
   viewBox="0 0 4100 3075"
   sodipodi:docname="unsplash_kSvpTrfhaiU.svg"
   inkscape:version="1.0.1 (1.0.1+r73)">
  <metadata
     id="metadata8">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs6" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="740"
     id="namedview4"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="0.19284553"
     inkscape:cx="2039.629"
     inkscape:cy="1330.0801"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="0"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1" />
  <g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     inkscape:label="Image"
     id="g10"
     sodipodi:insensitive="true">
    <image
       sodipodi:absref="/tmp/test/unsplash_kSvpTrfhaiU.jpg"
       xlink:href="unsplash_kSvpTrfhaiU.jpg"
       id="image12"
       preserveAspectRatio="none"
       height="3075"
       width="4100" />
  </g>
  <g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     inkscape:label="annot">
    <path
       style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:0.254573;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:16;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="M 29.740335,503.75775 363.73603,38.774206 3583.9418,25.941492 4063.2405,503.75775 2187.6326,810.27606 v 197.63004 l 260.7943,438.302 -220.7943,359.1655 h -296.8699 l -254.9643,-359.1655 273.6888,-438.302 V 810.27606 Z"
       id="path838"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccccccccc" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Right - so this is how the .svg looks like in Inkscape:

[image: inkscape]

If I open it in an image viewer like `eog` (Eye of Gnome), all looks fine:

[image: eog]

But if I open the .svg directly in a browser (that is what I mean by "standalone" - the .svg is not loaded from a .html page, but directly ; I do not mean "self-contained", because this .svg is not "self-contained", since it links, and does not embed, the photo image data) - it gets opened at its official pixel size, and so only a small part of it is viewable:

[image: firefox]

Then, I have to use Ctrl-Mouse Wheel to scale the .svg image in the browser, to have it show in full:

[image: firefox-scaled]

So, here is my question - is there any way, to load a "standalone" .svg directly (that is, *without* handling it via a separate .html page), so that when it loads in the browser, the initial view in the browser is "full-size", that is, the entirety of the .svg ; that is - the same as in the screenshot [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osZHA.jpg)?

Maybe I can add some directives to the SVG itself? Or call it with some query string in the browser, e.g. `file:///tmp/test/unsplash_kSvpTrfhaiU.svg?scale=full`?

Comment: Inkscape is ignoring the SVG width and height here, the browser is not. Arguably inkscape shouldn't do that. Better still you should change the outer element width and height to 100% rather than the large fixed values you're using now.

Comment: Many thanks @RobertLongson - changing "*the outer element width and height to 100%*" worked! Changed  `width="4100" height="3075"` of the main `<svg>` element to `width="100%" height="100%"`, and now the svg opens full view in Firefox! Feel free to post this as an answer, I'll accept it. (Btw, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by Inkscape ignoring the width/height - the rulers in the Inkscape screenshot show that the image dimensions are those listed in both the viewBox and width/height - the view just shows "all" of the image).